# Cannot access docker container due to wrong configuration

Tags: docker, apache

I have a docker container that runs apache2, due to some modification in `apache2` `sites-enables-SSL` file, I entered the wrong certificate name in the `.conf` file and this prevents me to access the container anymore.

Is there any way to undo my changes to be able to access the container again?

Comment: Is that container up and running?

Comment: have you tried using `docker exec` to enter the container and edit the Apache configuration file? that can help if only the container is up and running.

Comment: it was up, but due to this changes, i got  Container f0a862502bdabca895242443e963bf8f29b6b9352ba310219772229c07b5ef72 is restarting, wait until the container is running,

Comment: I tried using docker exec , but I cannot access it, it gets me out within seconds or sometimes I got the same error (wait until the container is running..)

Comment: is there a way to access apache2 sites-enabled directory using Winscap to undo my changes?

Comment: `docker rm` the broken container and `docker run` a new one.

Comment: Undo what change? Docker images are immutable. Either build a fixed image by editing your Dockerfile or mount a new conf file over the existing one

Comment: only I changed the certificate name in apache ssl.conf inside the container. I have a limited experience in docker could you please explain more about how to mount a new conf file over the existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, by

1. `sudo docker cp f0a862502b7a:/etc/apache2/sites-available /opt/`
2. `vi /opt/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` and undo the changes and save
3. `sudo docker cp /opt/sites-available/default-ssl.conf f0a862502b7a:/etc/apache2/sites-available`
4. restart the container and it works

Comment: Hi, remember to format your code with markdown tools. This makes answers readable on the fly. [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)